# Почему срабатывает offset на большом разрешении?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, flexbox

В коде стоит col-xs-offset1 почему отступ ставится работает на большом разрешении?
[image]
Если убрать xs-offset всё становится красиво 
[image]
Но тогда страдает мобильная версия 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Идет наследование `offset`, чтобы убрать его надо прописать класс `col-*-offset-0`. Где `*` это `md` или `lg`.

Comment: Я всё туда прописал <div class="my-flex-block-presentation col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-md-3 col-xs-10 col-lg-3 featured_article_padding">

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)